# Create a vector for k-folds (ID specific) in R

Tags: r, k-fold

I've been trying all kind of things, but it all ended up in error messages and weird stuff. I'm using a function from SurvSL at the moment, but I want to fine tune it a little for my specific needs. Here is the full function:

```
#function to compute k-fold cross-validated concordance index for Lasso-Cox, Ridge-Cox, EN-Cox
  c_indexCv_combined1 = function(data,k){
  y_dat = Surv(data$obs.time,data$status)
  set.seed(1)
  folds = sample(rep(1:k, length.out = nrow(data)))
  prediction_lasso = c()
  prediction_ridge = c()
  prediction_net = c()
  index =c()
  for (j in 1:k){
    idx = which(folds==j)
    train = data[-idx,]
    test = data[idx,]
    y_train = Surv(train$obs.time, train$status)
    y_test = Surv(test$obs.time,test$status)
    x = model.matrix(~., data[,-c(1,2)])
    fit_lasso = glmnet(x[-idx,],y_train, family="cox", alpha=1)
    cvFit_lasso = cv.glmnet(x[-idx,],y_train, family="cox", alpha=1)
    pred_lasso = predict(fit_lasso,x[idx,], s=cvFit_lasso$lambda.min, type="link") 
    fit_ridge = glmnet(x[-idx,],y_train, family="cox", alpha=0)
    cvFit_ridge = cv.glmnet(x[-idx,],y_train, family="cox", alpha=0)
    pred_ridge = predict(fit_ridge,x[idx,], s=cvFit_ridge$lambda.min, type="link") 
    fit_net = glmnet(x[-idx,],y_train, family="cox", alpha=0.5)
    cvFit_net = cv.glmnet(x[-idx,],y_train, family="cox", alpha=0.5)
    pred_net = predict(fit_net,x[idx,], s=cvFit_net$lambda.min, type="link") 
    index = c(index,idx)
    prediction_lasso = c(prediction_lasso, pred_lasso)
    prediction_ridge = c(prediction_ridge, pred_ridge)
    prediction_net = c(prediction_net, pred_net)
  }

  Match = match(seq(nrow(data)), index)
  prediction_lasso = prediction_lasso[Match]
  prediction_ridge = prediction_ridge[Match]
  prediction_net = prediction_net[Match]
  c_lasso = survConcordance(y_dat~prediction_lasso)$concordance
  c_ridge = survConcordance(y_dat~prediction_ridge)$concordance
  c_net = survConcordance(y_dat~prediction_net)$concordance
  final_pred = cbind(prediction_lasso, prediction_ridge, prediction_net)
  return(list(pred = final_pred, c_index=c(c_lasso, c_ridge, c_net)))
}
```

Now what I need to change is this part:

```
folds = sample(rep(1:k, length.out = nrow(data)))
```

folds becomes a vector with 1459 times a number between 1 and 5 so that I can "fold" my 1459 observations accordingly (in 5 groups of k=5). However, there is an "ID" variable in my data. Most of the time it's a unique number. But sometimes there are doubles/triples. It is very important that the same ID numbers get the same fold number (and that I don't have the same ID in two different folds). I have 1459 observations and 1240 different "ID"s. If I want 5 folds (k) there should be (1240/5=) 248 different ID numbers per fold.

Does anyone know a cool/simple function to manage this? After a lot of fooling around in R, I'm starting to fear that I will have to create that vector manually for 1459 obs...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first sample the unique IDs and then match up the rows. Example:

```r
k <- 5
set.seed(1)
samplepool <- paste0("ID_", sprintf("%04d", 1:1240))
df <- data.frame(idx=1:1459, 
    ID=sort(c(sample(samplepool, (1459-1240), replace = TRUE), samplepool)))
folds <- sample(rep(1:k, length.out = length(unique(df$ID)))) 
folds <- folds[match(df$ID, unique(df$ID))]
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So in your code, assuming the ID variable `ID`, you would replace

```r
folds = sample(rep(1:k, length.out = nrow(data)))
```

with

```r
folds = sample(rep(1:k, length.out = length(unique(data$ID))))
folds = folds[match(data$ID, unique(data$ID))]
```